# How to update "Going? Yes/No/Maybe" in Google calendar via API?

Tags: google-calendar-api

I am using Google Calendar API to work with events. For example, someone create an event and invites me. So, at the bottom of the event's detail I have 3 options of "**Going**": **YES**/**NO**/**MAYBE**. My question is how can I answer this by API?

I tried to use an `UPDATE` request, but it will create a new version of the event in my own calendar instead.

```
calendar.events.update(
  {
    calendarId: "primary",
    eventId: event.id,
    resource: {
      start: {
        dateTime: event.start.dateTime,
      },
      end: {
        dateTime: event.end.dateTime,
      },
      attendees: [
        {
          email: "myemail@gmail.com",
          responseStatus: "accepted",
        },
      ],
    },
  },
  (err, response) => {
  }
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example, how about using `patch` instead of `update` as follows?

#### Modified script:

```
calendar.events.patch(
  {
    calendarId: "primary",
    eventId: event.id,
    resource: {
      attendees: [
        {
          email: "myemail@gmail.com",
          responseStatus: "accepted",
        },
      ],
    },
  },
  (err, response) => {
  }
)
```

#### Reference:

- [Events: patch](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/patch)

Comment: @KaZaT Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.